# How to get the client IP address in asp.net when user runs hosted IIS link

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I hosted my code in IIS,I want to get the user Ip when any user logged into my application using my hosted link.
For example if 10 different users were accessed my link from 10 different systems means ,I want to get all those 10 different IP address in asp.net c#.
Is that same code will bring both server and IP address .I’m using Asp.net 4.5 -c#

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST")
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

Or...

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Item("X-Forwarded-For")
```

...if your server is behind a proxy. Be aware that the last one can be faked quite easily (and IPs are fakable/alterable too), so don't rely on it for anything related to security

Comment: Hi caius,this is not working.can u share me the code lines

Comment: As a bug report, "this is not working" doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

You can get client IP by this code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get your IP address like this :

```
var remoteIpAddress = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```